# Apache Phoenix check configuration or tuning are valid

Tags: database, hbase, apache-phoenix

Recently i configure/tuning based on this [link](https://phoenix.apache.org/tuning.html)

so how can i make sure that my tuning are valid and running?
is there a page or a code that can be proof of my tuning?

Thank before.

Comment: How about benchmarking a big query before and after tuning, and comparing the performance?

Comment: @AfshinMoazami Thank for the reply, performance test only solve some but not all the tuning.  but Thank for the suggestion. I realy appreciate it.

Comment: You are right, but the tuning settings on that page are not the best for every use case. So, it would be useless to have sample code to prove if you did it correct. The idea is to tune based on your application, and test (either performance, resources or any other criteria that you have) to see if it is better or not. If there was one best solution, that configuration would come out of the box